# Unexpected Token When sendGrid or nodemailer uploaded on the Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

Node-mailer or sendGrid is working fine on the local side but when I uploading / publishing on the Azure then its showing as Unexpected token {........

```
var sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

sgMail.setApiKey(Constants.sendGridKey);   
             var msg = {
                to: toWhomSendEmail,
                from: Constants.emailID,
                subject: "Message from ....",
                text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
                html: htmlBody
            };
            sgMail.send(msg, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    data("false");
                } else {
                    data("true");
                }
            });           

  ------------   Azure logging errors are just like: ---------------


Mon Apr 08 2019 15:43:02 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): 
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@sendgrid\mail\src\mail.js:6:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the prerequisite for using Send grid in Azure :

1) Node.js version 6, 7 or 8

2) Send grid account

Can you please ensure if you the requested version  for node. and then tryout these code.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    const msg = {
      to: 'test@example.com',
      from: 'test@example.com',
      subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
      text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
      html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
    };
    sgMail.send(msg);
```

hope it helps.